# When are non-static C++ data members allocated?

Tags: c++, memory, c++17

I have a class which passes the address of one data member to the constructor of another:

```
class MemberA {
 public:
  MemberA(MemberB* ptr) : ptr_(ptr) {}

 private:
  MemberB* ptr_;
};

struct MemberB {
 public:
  MemberB(int x) : x_(x) {}

 private:
  int x_;
};

class Foo {
 public:
  Foo() : a(&b), b(1) {}

 private:
  MemberA a;
  MemberB b;
};
```

In this example, `a` is constructed before `b`, but depends on the address of `b`. Would this work? My intuition says that data members are allocated at the start, so that `Foo` knows how large it needs to be, and also because they're allocated on the stack. However, I don't know this for a fact and would like to verify.

As an aside, I know that flipping the order would resolve this issue entirely; if `b` were declared and initialized before `a`, then I'd *know* that it would work. I also realize that even if the address is known, that dereferencing `b_` before it's initialized is undefined behavior. However, I'm really just curious if the above scenario is even legal

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data members are allocated within the object itself. Most of this is not specified in the standard, but that's how most compilers do it:

```
-- FOO --------------------------------------------
| --MemberA---   --MemberB---                     |
| |          |   |          | other stuff follows |
| ------------   ------------                     |
---------------------------------------------------
```

So, when `Foo F;` is constructed, before its `b` is initialized, it's address is already known relative to `Foo F`. So the address of `b` can be passed to `a`'s constructor. If `a` were to access this address during its construction, though, undefined behaviour would occur. But just storing the address for later? That will work.

Comment: But remember to respect [the Rule of Three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) or other badness will happen.

Comment: @user4581301: Where is the rule of three broken in this answer or in the question?

Comment: It isn't, but one bad copy and all bets are off.